# Name multiple plots with lapply(ggplot + ggtitle) with nested list name accordingly

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

My question is similar to this question but the difference is that my nested data frames in the list are named.
[How can I make multiple ggplots from a list of dataframes and have them on one pdf page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588761/how-can-i-make-multiple-ggplots-from-a-list-of-dataframes-and-have-them-on-one-p)

The code below applied the same title to all my plots (I added `ggtitle` to the original one).
All the four graphs were named `v1`, which is the first column name in each `df`.
I expected plots to be named `df1`,`df2`,..., or perhaps `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`,...

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1:5), v2=c(2:6))
df2 <- data.frame(v1=c(10:50), v2=c(20:60))
df3 <- data.frame(v1=c(100:500), v2=c(200:600))
df4 <- data.frame(v1=c(1000:5000), v2=c(2000:6000))
df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

lapply(df.list, function(d) ggplot(data = d, aes(x=v1, y=v2)) + ggtitle(names(d)) + geom_point() )
```

How do I change my code? Thank you!

Comment: You would need to iterate over `df.list` and `names(df.list)` with `Map` : `library(ggplot2);
Map(function(d, n) { ggplot(data = d, aes(x=v1, y=v2)) + ggtitle(n) + geom_point() }, d = df.list, n = names(df.list))`

Comment: `lapply` would work similar to the for loop in the linked post: `lapply(seq_len(length(df.list)), function(x) { ggplot(df.list[[x]], aes(x=v1, y=v2)) + ggtitle(names(df.list)[[x]]) + geom_point() })`

Comment: Thank you. The first solution is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this also:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Names
names(df.list) <- paste0('df',1:4)
#Code
lapply(seq_along(df.list), function(i) {
  ggplot(df.list[[i]], aes(x=v1, y=v2)) + 
    geom_point()+ 
    ggtitle(names(df.list)[i]) })
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And as **@markus** cited, you will need names in your list.